# What Are the Ideas Behind Variations of the Coin Change Problem?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

> Problem: given a set of `n` coins of unique face values, and a value
>   `change`, find number of ways of making change for `change`.

Assuming we can use a denomination more than once, here's the pseudocode I came up with

```
1. NUM-WAYS(denom[], n, change)
2.   dp = [change + 1][n + 1]
3.   for i = 0 to n
4      dp[i][0] = 1
5.   xs = denom.sorted

6.   for i = 1 to change
7.     for j = 1 to n
8.       if xs[j - 1] > i
9.         dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 1]
10.      else
11.        dp[i][j] = dp[i - xs[j - 1]][j] + dp[i][j - 1]

12.  return dp[change][n]
```

The above algorithm is clear to me. However, if we are only allowed to use a denomination once, then line 11 changes to `dp[i - xs[j - 1]][j - 1] + dp[i][j - 1]`, as if we are not allowed to use the current denomination at all. I'm failing to wrap my head around this. Can you explain this?

Here're some test runs:

```
Change: 3, denominations: [8, 3, 1, 2]
11111
01111
01222
01233

// use once
Change: 3, denominations: [8, 3, 1, 2]
11111
01111
00111
00122

Change: 4, denominations: [3, 1, 2]
1111
0111
0122
0123
0134

// use once
Change: 4, denominations: [3, 1, 2]
1111
0111
0011
0012
0001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `dp[i][j]` denote the solution to the `[i, j]`-th subproblem; that is,
`dp[i][j]` is the number of ways to make change for the amount `i`, using coins `j` through `n`.

### Coin Change Problem with Repetition

- The first case assumes that a single coin of the `j`-th denomination was taken. Since there's no constraint on the denominations, `j` may remain the same so it can be used again for smaller subproblems: `dp[i - xs[j - 1]][j]`.

### Coin Change Problem without Repetition

It's the same as the above problem with an additional constraint that a coin of some denomination can be only taken once.

- The first case assumes that a single coin of the `j`-th denomination was taken. Since we can't use denomination `j` anymore, `j` changes to `j-1`: `dp[i - xs[j - 1]][j - 1]`

The second case is the same in both problems where the `j`-th denomination is ignored.

Comment: Thanks. I edited your answer to fix some of the problems like typos and redundancy.

Comment: Thank you, it's way better now.